# PHP: Select part of string by letters UPPER/LOWER

Tags: php, algorithm

i'm novice in PHP and I block to a problem...

I have this string :

```
$player1 = "Gary PaytonINACTIVE";
$player2 = "Jabari ParkerOUT";
```

and I need to select ONLY from the `$player1` "INACTIVE" and the `$player2` "OUT". I begin to invert the string like that :

```
$player1 = strrev("Gary PaytonINACTIVE");
$player2 = strrev("Jabari ParkerOUT");
// $player1 = "EVITCANInotyaP yraG"
// $player1 = "TUOrekraP irabaJ"
```

Now my idea is to select the first uppercase letters, cut the rest and return in the good way the letters(with again a strrev()).. **but I have no idea how to make that...**

So, the question is: My idea start is good? Or there is a better solution to extract INACTIVE and OUT to the variables?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regular Expression `/([A-Z]{2,})\b/`

Try this

```
<?php
$player1 = "Gary PaytonINACTIVE";
$player2 = "Jabari ParkerOUT";

function getUppercase($string){
    preg_match('/([A-Z]{2,})\b/', $string, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}

echo getUppercase($player1); //INACTIVE
echo '<br>';
echo getUppercase($player2); //OUT
```

Comment: Thanks to your reply, this work for the exemple that I showed! But sometimes I have some exception like : `$player3 = "J.J. RedickGTD";` this begin by 3 upper letters and the result show is "RGTD" ... this is why i think to my first idea who read only the first Upper letters when we invert the string by `strrev()` but i dont know how read the first lower letter and cut the rest ....

Comment: `echo getUppercase($player3); //GTD` is still working, please give another exception example

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also

```
$player1 = "Gary PaytonINACTIVE";
$player2 = "Jabari ParkerOUT";

function getValue($value)
{
preg_match_all("/[[:upper:]]+/u", $value, $matches);
    foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
        if(strlen($match) > 2) {
        echo $match;    
        }
    }

}

getValue($player1);
echo '<br/>';
getValue($player2);
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! But it remains the same problem of the first answer  if i have a name who have 3 or 4 uppercase letters ! Other idea ?

Comment: Give me some example of name